# agm-snazzy-info-window for Angular 4 on Map Load without the marker

Tags: angular

I want to load a snazzy-info-window on Map load , and dont want it to be associated with any marker or marker click ( more like need the snazzy-info-window to display information for a location at the load of the map itself). Can someone please suggest how to do it. I have used the following code, but it does not display the info window

```
<agm-map [latitude] = "lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom] = "zoom">
<!-- <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" label = "MARK"></agm-marker> -->
<agm-snazzy-info-window [maxWidth]="200" [closeWhenOthersOpen]="true">
<ng-template>
My first Snazzy Info Window!
</ng-template>
</agm-snazzy-info-window>
</agm-map>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do it like it says on their website:
[Snazzy Info Window & Angular Google Maps website](https://angular-maps.com/guides/snazzy-info-window/custom-info-windows-with-snazzy-info-window/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231